# How do I Import/Sync Custom Azure AD fields into SharePoint Online UPS?

Tags: powershell, ad, ups

The title says it all. I found a Microsoft Blog that sort of explains it, but the jargon is above my level. I've never used Powershell and I haven't written C#.

https://dev.office.com/blogs/introducing-bulk-upa-custom-profile-properties-update-api

Could someone walk me through the steps? And what permissions do I need to accomplish this?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: You can take a look at this solution, https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.UserProfiles.Sync, but you will need to compile it on your own with Visual Studio.

Comment: If you want to make that an Answer, I think it IS the answer I am looking for. :) Granted it's not a step by step, but the Github repo does a fairly succinct job of walking me through their application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has multiple examples of solutions depending on the scenario you're after. Here's a brief list from their PnP GitHub repo.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/UserProfile.Manipulation.CSOM

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.UserProfilePropertyUpdater

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.UserProfiles.Sync